# not showing GDAL raster tools

Tags: raster, gdal, tools

I have installed QGIS 3.22.14 on two computers. Both win11, 64-bit. On one computer I can see the GDAL Raster tools, and on the other I cannot. System variables show that GDAL is installed. The computer that works ans GDAL/OGR version 3.5.1, the computer that does not work has version 3.6.1 installed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with MacOS